# Mac OS X terminal and PATH variable

Tags: macos, mac, bash, unix

I've added PATH variable definition to my `~/.profile` file:
Here it is:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/
:~/Documents/development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/mighter/.profile file was backed up as /Users/mighter/.profile.macports-saved_2012-12-24_at_16:42:03
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-12-24_at_16:42:03: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

The problem is that every time I launch terminal I have following output:

```
-bash: :~/Documents/development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure that all dirs exist, and can't get the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra newline in your PATH line.

The PATH definition must be in one line, with each directory separated by a colon (`:`).